# Return binary string from decimal->binary conversion instead of printing values

Tags: c++, recursion, binary

I've created a program that recursively converts decimals into binary and prints the value to the screen.

However, I want this program to return a `string` that contains the 1's and 0's that make up the binary number.  I've tried a bunch of ways unsuccessfully, and I'm not sure how to implement this change.

```
void decToBin(int n) {
    int remainder;
    remainder = n%2;
    if(n > 0) {
        decToBin(n/2);
        cout << remainder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing the digit to `cout`, append it to the string. Then return the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an in-memory stream instead of `std::cout`, and return the buffer at the end:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string decToBin(int n) {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    int remainder = n % 2;
    if (n > 0) {
        stream << decToBin(n / 2);
        stream << remainder;
    }
    return stream.str();
}
```

That said, this *is* quite inefficient, because there are lots of string allocations. You probably want an iterative algorithm rather than a recursive one, so that you need only one string stream.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the return value of `decToBin` to `std::string`.
2. Concatenate the string representation of `remainder` to  return value of the recursive call with to the function and return it.

```
std::string decToBin(int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << n%2;
        return decToBin(n/2) + s.str();
    }

    // The terminating condition.
    return "";
}
```

The function can be reduced to a one liner using:

```
std::string decToBin(int n)
{
   return (n > 0) ? decToBin(n/2) + std::string(1, (n%2+'0')) : "";
}
```

Comment: `std::ostringstream` doesn't fit here like perhaps a ternary conditional/`'0' + n / 2`/`std::to_string`.

Comment: @LogicStuff, I didn't follow what you are trying to say. Would you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @R Sahu Only that the `if`-clause would be a one-liner with any of mentioned alternatives.

Comment: @LogicStuff, I see. There are definitely more than one ways to solve the problem.